# WiX: heat how to use custom variable in command line

Tags: wix, windows-installer, heat

I'm using this heat command

```
heat dir "$(SolutionDir)scr\A\A.WindowsService\bin\$(Configuration)" -dr ConfigurationUtilityDir -gg -g1 -cg ConfigurationUtilityComponents -sf -spdb -xo -srd  -out "$(SolutionDir)scr\Installers\A\AInstallerHeat\ConfigurationUtilityHeat.wxs" -dPath="C:\..\A\A.WindowsService\bin\Release -var var.Path
```

but seems that heat ignores the declaration of the 'Path' variable and the -var parameter. So it generates a file like this

```
<Component Id="cmpBBD96B447087B68960C29FA13E08DCA2" Directory="dir5624AEB1C4C7EFEEFB6B6016AAE1AD54" Guid="B71EF27A-2812-4698-BDA9-8ABC8C44C8F7">
   <File Id="fil8D456C6334925F4FE3A7B8A8A5D76ABB" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\bin\A.dll" />
</Component>
```

Obviously, it can't creates a final .msi package because it doesn't found any file at the path declared in 'Source' attribute.

How can I use the 'Path' variable value as 'Source' attribute?

Thanks

EDIT: I tried also to use `-b C:\..\A\A.WindowsService\bin\Release` instead of define a custom variable, but it still looks for files into 'SourceDir.." directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain how I achieve what you are asking using Visual Studio, and maybe that will help you figure out a solution.

1. In my heat command, instead of `-var var.Path` I specify `-var wix.Path`.
2. In the Tool Settings window for my Visual Studio project properties, I specify in the linker options `-dPath=..\someRelativePath`

When heat.exe generates the source, the path specified is now in the form `Source="!(wix.HelpSource)\filename.dll"`

Here is a screenshot of what the Tool Settings window looks like:
[image]

Note: As mentioned in the other answer, when running heat.exe, the last parameter specified is the output file `-out sourceFile.wxs`.

Comment: Is it possible to use environment variables or the Pre-build/Post-build macro values in the Linker options somehow?

Answer (score 0):

From heat Usage:

```
usage:  heat.exe harvestType harvestSource <harvester arguments> -o[ut] sourceFile.wxs
```

No more arguments are parsed after the -o[ut] argument. You have -dPath... and -var after -out.